# webMathematica interface for Mobile apps

Tags: webmathematica

I was reading about webmathematica but it has mentioned that it is for websites and mobile apps depend on wolfram alpha to get its work done. But since exact mathematica code doesn't work in alpha, it obviously puts serious limitations regarding the granularity of computation needed as it is at mercy of database.

So, is there some service that some app can be programmed that creates mathematica code based on parameters from front-end and it is sent as request object to some server where it can be computed and sent back as response object, hence giving the exact answer.

In simpler words, Mathematica running on server and executing client's code.

Comment: Maybe the title is misleading, but you can already use webMathematica with a mobile phone. For instance, have a look at the examples [here](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/examples/examples.html).

Comment: I have already seen this link and it refers to those websites that use it and some examples..it doesn't mention mobile anywhere.

Comment: webMathematica is completely independent of Wolfram|Alpha. Please read [this](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/whatis.html), and, if you are entitled, get the webMathematica amateur yourself, study it for a few weeks or months, and then you see how it all works.

Comment: I thought of doing this but I thought if someone has clear idea already in case..thanks

Comment: Sorry to insist, but can you use your mobile phone to check out the examples in the link and see if/how they work for you ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, a lot of these webMathematica examples requires flash!.. They will not work in an iPhone or iPad for example.

Answer (score 1):

WebMathematica supports JSP. You can use any front-end framework (Bootstrap, Foundation or [alternatives](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-alternatives/)) that supports responsive design. So it can be used to create a mobile UI that works with web too.

Next step could be using this UI to create a REST API. Off course what you want to do within the API/Service is left to your use case. Being a backend developer, I think any backend service may have to manage database (Create,Read,Update and delete tables/collections etc) and pass it to the query handling function for some analysis. In your case you could use MongoDB (or any other) as database, query it using your UI (see msp tags), passing it to the mathematica code for analysis and lastly rendering the output as image etc (See MSPShow[] etc).

I wrote a simple explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111929/2425) on REST Like web service.